# Incidence algebra the zeta and Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

I kinda came up with this problem, and I was confused about where or how the zeta and Möbius matrix from the graph is achieved. The given graph is [image]

From the article, the zeta function is defined as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
 \zeta(a,b)=\{ 0 \space \text{if} \space a\nleq b; 1 \space \text{if} \space a\leq b
\end{aligned}$$

This is the part where I was confused, about how the matrix is constructed: the zeta matrix corresponding to the set P={a,b,c,d} is shown below:

[image]

Comment: The zeta function is like an indicator function for a given partial order.

Comment: that's the only one provided definitions in the article, so its hard for me to understand on how the zeta matrix is constructed like that

Comment: The diagram is a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram). That $d$ is above $a$ means that $a \leq d$ (via either $b$ or $c$, the partial order implied by the diagram is transitive (what with being a partial order)). As in, you can read the diagram as saying $x \leq y$ if and only if you can get from $x$ to $y$ by only going upwards. Then use the definition of your $\zeta(x, y)$ to fill in the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the partially ordered graph, we can see that $a\leq b\leq d$ and $a\leq c\leq d$. We can contstruct a table of all possible inputs:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & y & \zeta(x,y) \\
\hline
a & a & 1 \\
\hline
a & b & 1 \\
\hline
a & c & 1 \\
\hline
a & d & 1 \\
\hline
b & a & 0 \\
\hline
b & b & 1 \\
\hline
b & c & 0 \\
\hline
b & d & 1 \\
\hline
c & a & 0 \\
\hline
c & b & 0 \\
\hline
c & c & 1 \\
\hline
c & d & 1 \\
\hline
d & a & 0 \\
\hline
d & b & 0 \\
\hline
d & c & 0 \\
\hline
d & d & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

This, of course, it hard to read, so we can put it in a nice table the following way

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
 & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
a & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
b & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
c & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

where the left column of $a,b,c,d$ are the $x$-values, and the first row of $a,b,c,d$ are the $y$-values. So, for example, the entry of $(a,b)$ is $1$, which means that $\zeta(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Hi, this helps me a lot, thank you so much. I can now try to understand the Mobius matrix setting the example u give.

Comment: hi, in Mobius function, $\mu(a,d)$ is $-1$, but in the original matrix it is $1$, but looking at the hasse  diagram $a<d$ and $a\neq d$

Comment: @jennkim If you are unsure of how to find the mobius function for elements of this poset, it should be asked as a separate question, which should include your attempt and the definition of the mobius function that you are using.

Comment: oh okay maam/sir, ill do my attempt and definition of it thank you